# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime - Whats wrong?

Tags: c#, linq, date-format, formatexception

I have been getting an annoying littler error and cannot for the life of me figure out why it is being cause. I have an xml file where i am storing data, as shown below.

```
- <EmployeeFinance>
  <EmployeeEmploy_Id>5584</EmployeeEmploy_Id> 
  <EmpPersonal_Id>30358</EmpPersonal_Id> 
  <No_DaysWorked>30</No_DaysWorked> 
  <Date_Appointment>17/02/2012</Date_Appointment> 
  <Date_Employment>02/05/1984</Date_Employment> 
  <Date_Termination>01/01/0001</Date_Termination> 
  <Payperiod_StartDate>01/01/2013</Payperiod_StartDate> 
  <Payperiod_EndDate>31/01/2013</Payperiod_EndDate> 
  <BatchNumber>38</BatchNumber> 
  <PAYE_ToDate_Computed>0</PAYE_ToDate_Computed> 
  <Income_Tax_RateID>0</Income_Tax_RateID> 
  <NIS_RateID>0</NIS_RateID> 
  <NIS_weeks_worked>0</NIS_weeks_worked> 
  </EmployeeFinance>
```

If you look at the date nodes, Payperiod_StartDate,Payperiod_EndDate, Date_Appointment etc. They all have the same format. Now in my C# code, when i write my query to select from the xml file i get the **String was not recognized as a valid DateTime** error. WHen i comment out all the other dates and leave start_date, it works. They are the same format , i cant see what i am doing wrong. Please help me.

```
    var context = new SSPModel.sspEntities();
    XElement xelement = XElement.Load(GlobalClass.GlobalUrl);
    XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(GlobalClass.GlobalUrl);

    var query = from nm in xelement.Elements("EmployeeFinance")
                select new EmployeeEmploy
                {
                    Employee_Personal_InfoEmp_id = (int)nm.Element("EmpPersonal_Id"),
                    Substantive_designation = (int)nm.Element("Position_Id"),
                    Grade_Id = (int)nm.Element("Grade_Id"),
                    PositionTotal_PtBasic = (double)nm.Element("Sum_AllPosition"),//part of basic
                    GradeTotal_PtBasic = (double)nm.Element("Sum_AllGrade"), //part of basic
                    Housing_Allowance = (double)nm.Element("Housing"),
                    Base_Pay = (double)nm.Element("Base_Pay"),
                    startDate = (DateTime)nm.Element("Payperiod_StartDate"),
                    endDate = (DateTime)nm.Element("Payperiod_EndDate"),
                    Date_of_Appointment = (DateTime)nm.Element("Date_Appointment"),
                   Date_of_Employment = (DateTime)nm.Element("Date_Employment"),
                    Termination_date_actual = (DateTime)nm.Element("Date_Termination"),
                    Base_Pay_Currency = (string)nm.Element("Currency"),
                    Exchange_rate = (double)nm.Element("Exchange_Rate")
                };
    var x = query.ToList();
    foreach (var xy in x) {
        Debug.WriteLine(xy.endDate);
    }
```

Comment: You should be storing your dates in the XML file in a culturally neutral way. Preferably ISO 8601 format `17/02/2012` vs `2012-02-17`.  That would prevent this error.  The actual reason why you got this error is explained well from @GeorgeJohnston below.  Although you could have also solved it by making sure that the client you are using to read this file is set to your preferred culture so that the default DateTime.Parse would use your culture's settings instead of the culture invariant format which is `mm/dd/yyyy`

Answer (score 1):

Because `17/02/2012` is not a valid date, however, `02/17/2012` is.  The date will be parsed as `mm/dd/yyyy`.  One option is to use [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) to parse a date with the `dd` as the first set of numbers. e.g.

```
var startDate = DateTime.ParseExact("17/02/2012", "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

Comment: Can you help me out with the code a little.. im struggling with it. I have .. startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(nm.Element("Payperiod_EndDate").ToString(), "dd-MM-yyyy", null),

Comment: Get rid of the dashes -- use `/`

Comment: using what you said inside my query and i am still getting the error. startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(nm.Element("Payperiod_EndDate").ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", null),

Answer (score 0):

The debugger will show you that `nm.Element("Payperiod_EndDate").ToString()` gives you a string that includes the xml tags for that element. Try the following instead:

`startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(nm.Element("Payperiod_EndDate").Value, "dd/MM/yyyy", null)`